Nginx: Conflicting Server Names Error When Configuring Different Timeouts for Subdomains
I'm trying to configure Nginx with two server blocks to differentiate between the timeouts for a specific subdomain (subdomain.example.com) and the rest of the domain (*.example.com). However, my attempts result in the following error:
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "specific_subdomain.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
These are my two server blocks:
server {
    client_body_timeout 60;
    client_header_timeout 60;
    send_timeout 60;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name     *.example.com example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/example.com-0001.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/example.com-0001/privkey.pem; 

    location ~ /.well-known {
            default_type "text/plain";
            root /var/www/lets/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 60; # Timeout for reading a response from the proxied server
        proxy_pass http: //127.0.0.1:8083;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    send_timeout 10;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name     subdomain.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/example.com-0001.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/example.com-0001/privkey.pem; 

    location ~ /.well-known {
            default_type "text/plain";
            root /var/www/lets/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 10; # Timeout for reading a response from the proxied server
        proxy_pass http: //127.0.0.1:8083;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Question:
How can I configure Nginx to have different timeouts for subdomain.example.com and *.example.com without encountering the conflicting server name error?

Have you checked if you already have a server block for subdomain.example.com in a different configuration file?

please share the output of nginx -tT
